# Creating a bar(like Volume Bar or Progress bar) in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, progress-bar, move, touch-event

I want to create a Bar (like that of Volume Bar or Progress bar) . A Bar as such which is a rectangle and has a default colour say Black, then when i touch the bar from one side to other it changes colour to the point when i habe touch it

My research says one can use TouchEvent.MOVE for this .But am confused as to how to proceed about it Please Guide me

A Progress Bar as shown below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please download and configure sample code from the BlackBerry Developer Support Knowledge Base:
[Implement advanced buttons, fields, and managers](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276)